# Why I can not use the class created in javascript, but in html I put the same class in the element and it works fine

Tags: javascript, class

I have three buttons already created in html which will always be there on the page, and I gave the class of `isActive` to them.
The problem is when I create new buttons in JavaScript with the same class, the code given to this class doesn't work for the new ones added, only to the buttons in html

## html

```
<div class="top-menu-content">
        <div class="inbox">
          <button class="menu-btn isActive"><i class="fa-solid fa-inbox"></i>Todas</button>
        </div>
        <div class="today-tasks">
          <button class="menu-btn isActive"><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-week"></i>Semana</button>
        </div>
        <div class="completed">
          <button class="menu-btn isActive"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-double"></i>Concluídas</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

## add-project.js, Will add new buttons with the exactly same class

```
const projectNameInput = document.querySelector('.project-name-input')
const addProjectBtn = document.querySelector('.add-project-btn')
const bottomMenuContent = document.querySelector('.bottom-menu-content')
const allProjectsTxt = document.querySelector('.all-projects-txt')
let projectTitle;
function capitalize(s) {
    return s && s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
}

const addProject = (() => {
    addProjectBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Do not add if the input is empty
        if (!projectNameInput.value || projectNameInput.value === ' ') {
            alert('Não é póssivel adicionar um projeto sem um nome.')
            return
            // Add if not empty
        } else {
            bottomMenuContent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                `<div class="project">
                    <button class="project-name-btn isActive">${capitalize(projectNameInput.value)}</button>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left" onclick="return this.parentNode.remove();"></i>
                </div>`
            )
            // Get Project title
            const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.project-name-btn')
            for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                projectTitle = btns[i].textContent
            }
            console.log(projectTitle)
            allProjectsTxt.hidden = false
            projectNameInput.value = ''
            projectNameInput.type = 'reset'
            projectNameInput.type = 'text'
        }
    })
})()
```

## getActiveBtn.js, Get the button that has been clicked

```
const isActive = document.querySelectorAll('.isActive')
const main = document.querySelector('.main')
const mainHeading = document.createElement('h1')
main.appendChild(mainHeading)

const getActiveBtn = (() => {
    isActive.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            mainHeading.textContent = btn.textContent
        })
    })
})()
```

I created a file to manage the clicks on these buttons, but nothing works

Comment: Is it that "nothing works" or the classes aren't added or the class style isn't being applied?

Comment: You attach the listeners *once* to existing elements. If new elements are added, listeners are not attached to them. Just use [DOM event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) and don't fiddle with individual elements.